# If c power of all positive integers is an integer, then c is an integer

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

If $n^c$ is always an integer, where $n=1,2,3,\dots,$ then prove that $c$ is an integer.

How to prove this?

Hints will be greatly appreciated...

Comment: You mean that $n^c$ being an integer for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, positive integers $n$, implies that $c$ is an integer?

Comment: @hardmath yes i mean that

Comment: @mathlove Thank you for the link